# ZTE 3g modem connection issue

Tags: at-command, root

TRied connecting to the internet with ZTE 3g modem (tatadocomo3g)
DId a gprs attach - AT+CGATT+1 got an OK
Set PDPD context using - AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","tatadocomo3g","0.0.0.0",0,0 - got an OK
ACtivate pdp context 1 using AT+CGACT=1,1 . got OK for the same.
The 3g modem blinks (same behavior as when i do it from photon app) but does not connect to internet. Also do not see an IP address being allocated by GGSN.
JUst to confirm, it works fine with the Photon app provided on windows. I get an ip address and can connect to internet. DOnt understand what AT commands i missed while trying manually. Need help.

Comment: Sorry, this is wrong place to ask such questions. You'd better ask the same on http://superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

Try the dial command for PDP context no 1:

ATD*99***1#